# Does diagonals in a parrellogram divide it in four congruent triangles?

Tags: geometry

I read this in a book and on wikipedia also that diagonals in a parrellogram divide it in four congruent triangles. But my friend says they do not.

Can you please provide answer with proof?

Thanks

Comment: all of them have same area but they are not all congruent necessarily

Comment: This is false. To convince yourself about that, pick an A4 sheet of paper, and draw the diagonals. The lacking hypothesis here is that you need your quadrilateral to be a rhombus (all 4 sides congruent).

Comment: What is always true is that the diagonals in a parallelogram divide it in **two pairs** of opposite (i.e., vertex-to-vertex) congruent triangles.